# Is there any alternative to putting the password in the knexfile?

Tags: knex.js

I'm using knex migrations on the command line to set up my postgresql database (on Windows if it makes any difference). So far, the only option I can find for giving knex the username/password to the postgres database is to put it in the knexfile.

I'd rather not have a clear text password in the knexfile.

Comment: so, where would you like to put your password?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you read password and other connection settings from environment variable inside the `knexfile.js` like this

```
module.exports = {
  client: 'postgres',
  debug: false,
  connection: {
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT || 5432,
    user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER || 'postgres',
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_USER_PW || undefined
  }
};
```